# what is the best way to handle the id when insert record using rust diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am using rust diesel(`diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono"] }`) to insert a record into PostgreSQL 13, this is my rust code:

```
pub fn add_domain(request: &Json<AddDomainRequest>, login_user_info: LoginUserInfo) {
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let timestamp: i64 = get_current_millisecond();
    let new_domain = Domain {
        id: 0,
        domain_name: request.domainName.to_string(),
        domain_url: request.domainUrl.to_string(),
        created_time: timestamp,
        updated_time: timestamp,
        cron: Some("* */1 * * * *".parse().unwrap()),
        next_trigger_time: None,
        monitor_status: None,
        user_id: Option::from(login_user_info.userId),
        expire_date: None,
        days_before_trigger: 7,
        notify_trigger_date: None,
        expire_date_ms: None,
    };
    diesel::insert_into(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::domain::table)
        .values(&new_domain)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing()
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
}
```

I did not know how to handle the primary key id, the Domain model was auto generated(means that I could not modify the Domain because it will override the modification the next time auto generated), if I remove the id, I could not new a Domain, if I keep the id, the PostgreSQL database will show this error:

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: DatabaseError(__Unknown, "cannot insert into column \"id\"")', src/service/app/cernitor/domain/domain_service.rs:46:10
   >> Handler add panicked.
   >> This is an application bug.
   >> A panic in Rust must be treated as an exceptional event.
   >> Panicking is not a suitable error handling mechanism.
   >> Unwinding, the result of a panic, is an expensive operation.
   >> Panics will severely degrade application performance.
   >> Instead of panicking, return `Option` and/or `Result`.
   >> Values of either type can be returned directly from handlers.
   >> A panic is treated as an internal server error.
   >> Outcome: Failure
   >> No 500 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
   >> Response succeeded.
```

what should I do to make the diesel ignore the auto generate id? this is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public."domain" (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    domain_name varchar NOT NULL,
    domain_url varchar NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    cron varchar NULL,
    next_trigger_time timestamp(0) NULL,
    monitor_status varchar NULL DEFAULT 1,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    expire_date timestamp NULL,
    days_before_trigger int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 14,
    notify_trigger_date timestamp NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expire_date - make_interval(days => days_before_trigger)) STORED,
    expire_date_ms int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT domain_record_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I tried to tweak the entity like this:

```
#[derive(Insertable,Queryable,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Identifiable)]
#[primary_key(id)]
#[table_name = "domain"]
pub struct Domain {
    pub id: i64,
    pub domain_name: String,
    pub domain_url: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub cron: Option<String>,
    pub next_trigger_time: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub monitor_status: Option<String>,
    pub user_id: Option<i64>,
    pub expire_date: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub days_before_trigger: i32,
    pub notify_trigger_date: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub expire_date_ms: Option<i64>,
}
```

still did not fix it.

Comment: from my experience most probably you would have to implement `Insertable` yourself, skipping the id whatsoever.

Comment: I define another entity that did not contain the id field@Netwave

Comment: yes, that is another solution. But it is a bit bothersome to maintain both structures. It also have its on advantages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Insert without adding `id` field value in `Domain` struct we can make the id field optional by wrapping it with [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) type

```rs
#[derive(Default,Debug,Queryable,Identifiable,Insertable,Serialize,Deserialize)]
#[diesel(primary_key(id))]
#[table_name = "domain"]
pub struct Domain {
    #[diesel(deserialize_as = "i64")]
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub domain_name: String,
    pub domain_url: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub cron: Option<String>,
    pub next_trigger_time: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub monitor_status: Option<String>,
    pub user_id: Option<i64>,
    pub expire_date: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub days_before_trigger: i32,
    pub notify_trigger_date: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub expire_date_ms: Option<i64>,
}
```

Then while creating `Domain` instance we can pass [`None`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#variant.None) as value to `id` field.

#### **Note:**

**Explanation for `#[diesel(deserialize_as = "i64")]`**

While fetching result with [`get_results`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.get_result) we can encounter below issue:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<i64>: Queryable<BigInt, Pg>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:58:10
   |
58 |         .get_result(conn)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Queryable<BigInt, Pg>` is not implemented for `Option<i64>`
   |
```

The error is related to `id` field deserialization which states `BigInt` cannot be directly deserialize to `Option<i64>`

since `id` field is [`i64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html) in `Domain` struct and [`BigInt`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.BigInt.html) is also internally [`i64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html) we told diesel to deserialize `id` field as [`i64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html) with `#[diesel(deserialize_as = "i64")]` instead of [`BigInt`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.BigInt.html) while fetching which then can be mapped as `Option<i64>` to resolve the issue

Comment: Do you also add `id -> Nullable<Integer>` to your models?

Comment: @AlenSiljak as show in the answer id field is `Option<i64>`.

Comment: I am asking about the schema definition. The id field is a primary key, therefore non-nullable, but it has to be declared as nullable here.

Comment: @AlenSiljak table definition does not require any changes since id column is primary key it won't be empty or null

Comment: thanks. However, I'm getting an error if the table definition is not in sync with the model fields. So the id column needs to be Nullable<Integer> and the id field an Option<i32> (or Integer and i32 when non-nullable) in order to compile. I wish this was a bit simpler or explained somewhere in the docs.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, and throws a ton of errors.

Comment: @7skies I posted the code after testing locally, you may be using different rust or diesel version or there may be some other issue and I only tested it with postgres you may require additional changes for different db.

Comment: Awesome, work like a charm. Combine with ..Default::default() then I can avoid to define a lot of new structs just for Insertable